# Swagger does not generate JSON

Tags: java, json, rest, maven, jax-rs

Swagger does not generate the JSON file. My looks POM like this:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>my.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-restservice</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>my-restservice</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.github.kongchen</groupId>
                    <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <apiSources>
                            <apiSource>
                                <locations>my.path.to.the.service</locations>
                                <info>
                                    <title>${project.name}</title>
                                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                                </info>
                                <swaggerDirectory>${project.build.directory}/src</swaggerDirectory>
                                <outputFormats>json</outputFormats>
                            </apiSource>
                        </apiSources>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.16</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

This is a REST interface I implemented:

```java
@Path("/data")
@SessionScoped
@Api(value = "data")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class Data implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EJB
    private DataApi d;

    @GET
    @ApiOperation(value = "Returns all data")
    public Collection<DataObject> getData() {
        // Removed.
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @ApiOperation(value = "Returns data by id")
    public DataObject getData(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
        // Removed.
    }
}
```

I removed potential sensitive informations. Now When I build the project by `mvn clean install` the JSON file is not being generated. I am not using any JAX-RS implementation but just plain servlets. I am not sure whether that works though. What did I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have just found at least two problems. After resolving the problems, the JSON file is generated using the `mvn clean compile` command.

## 1. `pom.xml`: `build`: `pluginManagement` vs `plugins`

There is the `pluginManagement` definition of `swagger-maven-plugin`, but actually it is not used. It is necessary to include **additionaly** the plugin reference in the `plugins`:

```xml
<project ...>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            ...
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.kongchen</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

## 2. `locations` specification

The `location` element is missed in the current implementation, but it must be here:

> Classes containing Swagger's annotation @Api, or packages containing those classes can be configured here. Multiple values must be separated by commas. Example: `<locations><location>com.github.kongchen.swagger.sample.wordnik.resource</location><location>com.github.kongchen.swagger.sample.wordnik.resource2</location></locations>`
>
> — [GitHub - kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin: JAX-RS & SpringMVC supported maven build plugin, helps you generate Swagger JSON and API document in build phase.](https://github.com/kongchen/swagger-maven-plugin)

All in all, the `locations` specification must be corrected, for example, as follows:

```xml
<locations>
    <location>com.thecompany.service.Data</location>
</locations>
```

Hope this helps.